DataSnapshot.getValue() undocumented strange behaviour
What's going on here?
assertEquals(mapOf("161" to "a", "163" to "b"), Firebase.database.getReference("case").get().await().value)
assertEquals(mapOf("1" to "hello", "3" to "hi"), Firebase.database.getReference("case2").get().await().value)


java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<{1=hello, 3=hi}> but was:<[null, hello, null, hi]>



When the Firebase SDK encounters child properties with low-value numeric keys that are close to each other, it converts the values to an array. And since some consecutive keys are missing, those end up as null values in the array.
There is no way to disable this array coercion. So to avoid problems like this, I typically use a short alpha-numeric prefix for such keys. Like "key_1", "key_3", etc.
Also see: Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase and other questions about this array coercion.

This could do with being documented in the getValue description.

looking at the android sdk source it appears using the export format avoids the array coercion
